# Java: Rolling dices and output

Tags: java

Im trying to rolling dices and then system print 1 of the dices when im calling slaTarningar() inside class Player,

```
class Player{
    int armees = 0;
    int diceAmount = 0;
    Dice Dices[];
    Player(String playerType){
        armees = 10;
        diceAmount = ("A".equals(playerType)) ? 3 : 2;
        Dices= new Dice[diceAmount];
        for(int i=0;i<Dices.length;i++){
            Dices[i]=new Dice();
        }
    }
    void slaTarningar(){
        for(int i=0;i<Dices.length;i++){
            Dices[i].role();
        }
        System.out.println ("Dice: "+ Dices[1]);
    }
    void visaTarningar(){
        String allDices="";

        for(int i=0;i<Dices.length;i++){
            allDices += ", " + Dices[i];
        }
    }
}
class Dice{
    int value;
    Dice(){
        value=0;
    }
    void role(){
        int role;
        role = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        value=role;
    }   
}
```

All i get is my project name, and something weird else:

```
Dice: javaapplication9.Dice@9304b1
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: BTW, Dice _is_ plural.  The singular is _die_.  (Believe it or not)

Comment: Die, die, DIE!  OK hurry up and roll it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `toString` method to `Dice`:

```
class Dice{
    int value;
    Dice(){
        value=0;
    }
    void role(){
        int role;
        role = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        value=role;
    }   

    public String toString() { 
       return "" + value + "";
    }
}
```

Or add a `getValue` method:

```
class Dice{
    int value;
    Dice(){
        value=0;
    }
    void role(){
        int role;
        role = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        value=role;
    }   

    public int getValue() { 
       return value;
    }
}

//.. in other class:
System.out.println ("Dice: "+ Dices[1].getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dice{
    int value;
    Dice(){
        value=0;
    }
    void role(){
        int role;
        role = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        value=role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
       return value + "";
    }

}
```

You need to tell Java how to print a Dice object - otherwise it uses an internal representation (the object's class and its hash code) from `Object.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the object, not the value. Use

```
System.out.println ("Dice: "+ Dices[1]*.value*);
```

or you can add a toString() method to the Dice class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "toString" method to your Dice class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Dice.toString()

Answer (score 0):

Your argument to the `println` method is `"Dice: "+ Dices[1]`.

The `+` operator can concatenate a String with an arbitrary object, which it does by converting the object into a String first.  It's able to do this because of the existence of the `Object.toString()` instance method, which returns a string representation of any object.

That's what's being called here to convert `Dice[1]` into a string constant (what you see is the default implementation of `toString()` that's inherited from `Object`).

So, you have two options to resolve this:

1. Override `public String toString()` on your `Dice` class.  Be aware that this will be the default "string representation" of instances of your class anywhere that they're output as text, so choose something that makes sense in a general context.  Or:
2. Explicitly pass the value of the `Dice` reference into the println statement.  Something like `println("Dice: " + Dices[1].value)`.